# Se debe o no subir /nombre del proyecto/wwwroot/lib a github

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, gitignore

en un proyecto ASP.NET Core web con MVC y .NET5 he creado usando Visual Studio 2019 el archivo .gitignore (usando pestaña Team Explore, settings, repository settings, add ignore file)

Me he percatado que la herramienta no incluye la exclusión de la carpeta **nombre del proyecto/wwwroot/lib** que guarda paquetes como

- bootstrap,
- jquery,
- jquery-validation,
- jquery-validation-unobtrusive

Existe algún motivo para subir a github estos paquetes y por ello Microsoft no incluye en su generación de .gitignore? o es correcto excluirlos a través de .gitignore (en este caso manualmente)?

Comment: En la versión en inglés hay una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175902/asp-net-core-2-1-should-wwwroot-be-excluded-from-source-control). Tal vez te ayude.

Comment: abecés requieres actualizar gitignore con tus reglas... no es 100% responsabilidad del gestor de proyectos ...